# How to get associated Sites of a hubsite via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

ist there any information about getting the sites that are associated to a hubsite?
I don't want to use SharePoint API, because the rest of the application works via Graph API
thanks

Comment: It seems that Graph API doesn't support manage hub sites.

Comment: i don't want to manage, i  just want to read.
Perhaps there is a way using the search functions?!